# How do I hide a title without hiding the content by using *ngIf?

Tags: html, angular

Can I hide this title without hiding content? When I set "IsTitleDisabled" true, the content is hiding. I want to hide only "Title.PhoneInfo". Is there a way to do it?

```
<form-layout-content title="{{'Title.PhoneInfo'}}" *ngIf="!IsTitleDisabled">
<!-- content -->
</form-layout-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using a method which is name is getContentTitle() from .ts side. Thanks for helping.

```
    getContentTitle(): string {
return !this.IsTitleDisabled ? this._phoneInfoTitle : this.emptyString;
}
```

HTML side :

```
<form-layout-content title="{{getContentTitle()}}">
<!-- content -->
</form-layout-content>
```

Comment: This works, but performance-wise it's not very good. getContentTitle() will be called often, because angular has no way to know if the return value has changed without calling it again. It's better to have a `contentTitle` property in the class, and use a setter for `isTitleDisabled`.

Answer (score 1):

We can bind **title** based on your boolean check `IsTitleDisabled` to avoid it for entire content.

Do some changes like below,

```
<form-layout-content [attr.title]="!IsTitleDisabled ? {{'Title.PhoneInfo'}} : ''">
    <!-- content -->
</form-layout-content>
```

If not this `'Title.PhoneInfo'` specific like constants simply we can avoid `{{ }}`:

```
  <form-layout-content [attr.title]="!IsTitleDisabled ? Title.PhoneInfo : ''">
        <!-- content -->
  </form-layout-content>
```

Comment: Title.PhoneInfo is spesific and your first solution didn't work. It looks like just a title row like " !IsTitleDisabled ? Phone Informations : '' "

Comment: have you tried the second solution..? Also try to remove space before `!IsTitleDisabled`, edited my answer with same..

Comment: I cant try it because Title.PhoneInfo is spesific. I can't change it.